# How to get Twitter trending topics for a given day in a given location?

Tags: twitter

This is a question about the Twitter API, which doesn't provide any information on this issue.

It's possible to get the **current** trending topic for a location, for example: United States:

https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424977.json

where 23424977 is the location code for the United States.

It's also possible to get the hourly trending topic for a given day, but world-wide:

https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/daily.json?date=2012-06-10/

However, I have not been able to find out how to get the trending topics on a given day in a given location, that is, a way to combine these two separate calls together.

Anyone has a solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: there are some 3rd party APIs and services for that: https://trendogate.com | https://onurmatik.github.io/twitter-trending-topics-archive/ | https://market.mashape.com/onurmatik/twitter-trending-topics-archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get this information from twitter API directly. You must regularly query the locations you are interested in for current trends. If you are interested in covering the globe, then you will need some oAuth drones to get past 150/350 request limit per hour.

And then in no time you will have your own archive of trending topics.

Comment: ...provided you haven't been blacklisted by Twitter for abusing the terms of service with your drones, of course ;-)

Comment: Thanks izeed. I was hoping to get to historical trends, since for the worldwide trends it's possible to go back one month. Eventually if I start collecting them hourly, I will have them. And no, I'm not interested in the whole globe, only the US, so I would not need drones.